# Issue with HBase and .start-hbase.sh

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I configured `Hadoop` with one `Namenode` on my server up to now, and I would like to install `Pseudo-Distributed HBase`.

All settings are fine, but when I execute :

```
sudo ./start-hbase.sh
```

I get this: `root@localhost's password:`

And I could not find password even if I tried each possibility.
I changed root password but none effect.

Do you have any idea about this issue?

I already read some posts about this issue, but I don't find a way in order to solve my problem.

[image]

**hbase-site.xml** looks like this :

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
  <value>/usr/local/zookeeper</value>
</property>

<property>
 <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
 <value>true</value>
```

```
<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
<value>localhost</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>1</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
  <value>2181</value>
</property>
<configuration>
```

Comment: This is nothing to do with Hadoop or HBase; even a `sudo ls` will fail for the same reason. You just need to find the root password.

Comment: @BenWatson It's pretty strange because I redefined root password and it doesn't change this issue :/